# window.onload functions not working on chrome but on firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a basic windows.onload function [on a html page](http://testintro.com/story/index1.html).

That's working completely fine on Firefox and Edge as expected but not working on Chrome.

I am using the below code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            jQuery("#loader").hide();
            jQuery("#cont").show();
            jQuery("#cont > div").hide();
            jQuery("#game-start31").show();
       }, 3000);        
    };
});
```

Not sure if chrome does not like my code or I have violated any terms of them.

Can anyone please let me know where I am making mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: Yes, I have used that. Just edited my code with the complete set. And there are no errors on console

Comment: You are using an `onload` listener _inside_ another onload listener with jQuery. Simply remove one of these.

Comment: Hi @JeremyThille How can I combine both then? That means after 3 secs of page load... That's my motive

Comment: I tried your site in Chrome and it executed that code.

Comment: @Jituu You can simply put the `setTimeout()` right inside the function, without using `window.onload`.

Comment: @Barmar: That hasn't been recommended since jQuery 3 - the only recommended option is `jQuery(function(){ ... })`. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more.

Comment: Removing the "onload function" and keeping only the timeout worked for me. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: @RichardDeeming I know, but it's harder to see what I'm talking about when I write that format, and I worry that the readers won't understand. I'm not really thrilled about that deprecation.